# fragment bottom navigation bar clickable one time selected item

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-navigation-bar

When I click again to any item, same fragment view reloading every time. But I wanna do bottom navigation bar item one time clickable. how can i do this?

This is MainActivity.java codes

```
navigationMenu=findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigationMenu.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

   //navigationMenu.getMenu().getItem(2).setIcon(R.drawable.arrow_down);

    //I added this if statement to keep the selected fragment when rotating the device
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new UserHomeFragment()).commit();
    }
```

This is click listener codes

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        selectedFragment = new UserHomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_works:
                        selectedFragment = new UserWorksFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_completed_works:
                        selectedFragment = new UserCompletedFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_profile:
                        selectedFragment = new UserAccountFragment();
                        break;
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        };
```

Comment: This is expected as new fragment instance is instantiated in every switch case